# Inserting Row Into HTML Table within a FORM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to add a row to a table that is located in a form using javascript.  The code works when is it is outside of the <*form*> tags, but once the code is surrounded by <*form*>, added rows will popup for a few milli seconds and then disappear.

The attached code was tested on Firefox and Mozilla with the same results.  If I remove the <*form*> tags, the code works fine.   Any ideal on why <*form*> tags is causing a reload and making the added rows to disappear?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>

<script>
function addTableRow() {

    var len = $('#vendorstbl tr').length
    var table = document.getElementById("vendorstbl");
    var row = table.insertRow(len);
    var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell0.innerHTML = "<select id='test"+len+"'><option name='test"+len+"'>Apple</option><option name='test"+len+"''>Sony</option></select>";
    cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='25' id='product"+len+"' name='product"+len+"'' value='Enter Data'>";
}
</script>

<html>
<body>
    <h3>Adding Row To Table Test:</h3>

    <form>
        <table class='add' id='vendorstbl'>
        <tr><th>Vendor</th><th>Product</th></tr>
        </table>
        <button onclick='addTableRow()'>Add Row</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `button type="button"` to prevent the form to be submitted, or place the button outside of the form. A tip: Pass `-1` to insert methods, then the item is added to the end of the row/cell automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an AngularJS directive to accomplish this? 
A simple ng-Repeat with some formatting will accomplish this in only a few lines of code.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class="rowClass(person)">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xEyJZ/
Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat